# Import text file to python script to run terminal commands

Tags: python

I want to import an text file to python script, and then do an if condition, something like this:

Let's say that I have this in example.txt file:

```
os: ubuntu
required: no
```

And I want to do this:

```py
if os =="ubuntu" and if required== "no":
 (exec terminal command);
elif os =="debian" & if required== "yes":
 (exec another terminal command);
```

Ignore syntax errors, it was only for you to understand.

***EDIT***

Thanks to @zyad osseyran, I managed to get this.

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")

for x in f:
    x = x.split(':') 
    atribute = x[0]
    value = x[1]
```

How can I make this, turning into and dictionary? And, how to get the values from here, to make an IF Condition?

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: It seems like you can do some programming in Python. Now go ahead, read the file line by line, split it on the separation character, assign the variables and you're good to go.

Comment: @MichaelButscher nothing relevant so far, giving it a try.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I can, only basic python, but will give a try on what you said. Thank you

Comment: @mfx28 Hello. The reason you got those comments instead of an answer is because it is generally wanted for people asking questions in Stack Overflow to include their approach, its problem and what they do not understand, rather than just stating the objective. Because this way, firstly people do not know what you know (and don't) - e.g. do you know how to open files in python and read from them? do you know how to split strings in delimiters? Secondly, if people only posted the objective without their approaches, they would essentially have the community solve their problems for them.

Comment: @kyriakosSt I understand that, Thank you!
Edited the post by the way, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save the values to a dictionary, you can do the following:

```py
config = dict()                   # construct an empty dictionary. Fill it with key-value pairs a every iteration
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
for x in f:
   x = x.split(':') 
   attribute = x[0].strip()       # .strip() removes preceding and trailing whitespaces
   value = x[1].strip()
   config[attribute] = value      # save the attribute and its value to the dictionary
```

In this case `config` is the dictionary that has all values of assigned to `attribute` as keys and the corresponding `value`'s as values. I have also added the `.strip()` method to the items you read in order to remove any whitespaces (since the way your example.txt is formatted, `x[1]` will have values `" ubuntu"` and `" no"` rather than `"ubuntu"` and `"no"`).

Now you can construct your if statement like this:

```py
if config['os'] == 'ubuntu' and config['required'] == 'no':
    # exec terminal command
elif config['os'] == 'debian' and config['required'] == 'yes':
    # exec another terminal command
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
    f = open("demofile.txt", "r")

    for x in f:
      x = x.split(':') 
      attribute = x[0]
      value = x[1]
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Just order them in a nice dictonary and you can do
your if statements
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: okay, that gave me some help, now, the thing is. I don't get how can I make that turning into an dictionary. Can you give me some tips? Thanks in advance